# Re-colour individual elements in the Material Design XAML Toolkit - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using the [material design toolkit](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) in XAML, and have three different group boxes, I would like to be able to re-colour all there headers, which are currently purple, into green, yellow and red respectively. I've looked [here](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Custom-Palette-Hues) , but couldn't seem to set the colours correctly and unsure if there is a better way of doing this as the colouring will be specific to each element.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Image of the group boxs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert so I don't know if this is the correct way but if you put a resource dictionary in the GroupBox resources with the colour palette you want to use then it will colour the groupbox correctly.

```
<GroupBox Header="Red">
    <GroupBox.Resources>
        <GroupBox.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Red.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </GroupBox.Resources>
</GroupBox>
```

Do the same thing with the other groupboxes, changing the palette as required.

Comment: You should tag your question with the relevant topic that this question covers. For example, are you asking an XML question, ASP.NET, C#?